# Magento 2 Remove cart content when user log-out | Empty cart when logged back in

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cart, session, quote

Correct me if I'm wrong, but completely removing the cart content on customer log-out is not native to **Magento 2** is it?

I read about the "**Persistent cart**" but it seems to work only for removing the cart content on logout but when the user logs back in, they get their cart content back.

I try to achieve the following scenario:

1. Customer logs in to the website.
2. Adds a product to cart.
3. Logs out of the website.

   - Cart is empty (Persistent cart feature can do that)
4. Customer logs back in to the website.

   - **Cart is still empty** (Not sure if this can be achieved using native functionality)

If this can be done using Native features of Magento 2 that would be great. If not, has anybody done that before? Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution. I used Magento 2.2.

Basically you just have to listen for the `customer_logout` event and when it occures, clear the cart contents. The listening is done via an observer.

1. Create a custom module if you havn't already
2. In the module, create the file `/etc/frontend/events.xml` if it is not already present
3. The `events.xml` should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">

 <!-- Your other observers, if any -->

 <!-- Copy from here -->
 <event name="customer_logout"> <!-- use one of the events above -->
     <observer name="[Vendor]_[Name]" instance="[Vendor]\[Name]\Observer\Logout" />
 </event>
 <!-- to here -->
</config>
```

4. Set your modules's `[Vendor]` and `[Name]` accordingly
5. In the module, create the file `/Observer/Logout.php`
6. The content of the Logout observer class should look like this:

```
<?php

namespace [Vendor]\[Name]\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;

class Logout implements ObserverInterface
{
  protected  $cart;

  public function __construct(Cart $modelCart) {
      $this->cart = $modelCart;
  }

  public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
  {
      foreach($this->cart->getItems() as $item)
      {
          $this->cart->removeItem($item->getId());
      }
      $this->cart->save();
      $this->cart->saveQuote();  // I added both 'save' lines to make sure everything is persisted
      return $this;
  }
}
```

7. Make sure to enter `[Vendor]` and `[Name]` accordingly to your module and `events.xml`
8. Run `php bin/magento setup:di:compile` to set the observer active